# Error unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

I want to calculate the Mean of X columns as Matrix but got the subject error message however I have tried to convert the dataset to Integer through `Int` or `to_numeric` but didn't work

```
data = pd.read_csv('hw03_problem2.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
trainingYdf = data['mpg']
trainingXdf = data[['cylinders', 'displacement', 'horsepower', 'weight']]

Y = np.matrix(trainingYdf).T
X = np.matrix(trainingXdf)

X_columnMeans = X.mean(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at your input csv. If there is any line not containing a number, pandas read_csv will interpret each cell as a string. Therefore, your matrixes will not contain numbers, but strings, which will cause the error you observed. Using
`pd.read_csv('hw03_problem2.csv', skipinitialspace=True, dtype=int)`
will inform pandas, that you expect integers (replace with whatever numerical format your csv contains). However this will still fail, if there are cells inside your csv that contain text

**AFTER OP HAS EDITED HIS QUESTION**

your `trainingYdf` columns will still contain matrixes of strings, since np.matrix does not convert to numerical values.

```
tmp = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]]  
x = np.matrix(tmp)  
print(x)
```

will result in

```
[['1' '2' '3']
 ['4' '5' '6']]
```

Try to convert each entry in your 'trainingYdf' before casting to np.matrix (assuming that its single dimensional)

`trainingYdf = [float(x) for x in trainingYdf]`

Comment: When i added dtype=int CSV reade its giving me                                                       
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '18.0'

Comment: Python assumes that `18.0` is a float. Therefore, you have to change to `dtype=float`.
However, since you are accessing columns based on their names, I assume that your csv does in fact contain text. Then this will not work at all. Please see the second half of my answer on how to transform your list of strings in  `trainingYdf` and `trainingXdf`  to numbers before calling `np.matrix`